# Is there $L$ such that $L$ and $\bar L$ are context free, but $L$ is not deterministic context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties, nondeterminism

The usual candidates for context free languages whose complement is also context free, but they are not regular are the [Deterministic Context Free Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language) ($DCFL$).

For example, $L=\{a^nb^n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is such language.

> *Is there a language, $L\in CFL\setminus DCFL$ such that $\bar L\in
>  CFL$?*

---

Since $DCFL$ is closed under complement, this is equivalent of asking whether $$CFL\cap co\text{-}CFL = DCFL$$

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/the-class-cfl-cap-co-cfl/4264#4264):

> For every finite, non-unary alphabet, the language of all palindromes is not in DCFL, but in the intersection of coCFL and CFL.